# Update array and push object in same array of array using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

if I have structure like this then: 
I want to update dairyDailyLogs calories and push an object inside breakfast as per condition (condition to find object position in which this needs to be done)

```
"dairyDailyLogs":[
   {
      "breakfast":[
         {
            "mealType":1,
            "mealId":"5d758afe89527212109703d1"
         }
      ],
      "calories":100,
      "consumptionDateString":"5/15/2020"
   },
   {
      "breakfast":[
         {
            "mealType":1,
            "mealId":"5d758afe89527212109703d1"
         }
      ],
      "calories":100,
      "consumptionDateString":"5/16/2020"
   }
]
```

please help !!

These were main two attempts out of many other i made:

```
db.user_dairy.update({
  "dairyDailyLogs.consumptionDateString": "5/15/2020"
},
{
  $set: {
    "dairyDailyLogs.$": {
      "breakfast": [
        {
          mealType: 1,
          mealId: "5d758afe89527212109703d1"
        }
      ],
      calories: 200,
      consumptionDateString: "5/15/2020"
    }
  }
},
{});
```

and

```
db.user_dairy.updateOne({
  "dairyDailyLogs.consumptionDateString": "5/15/2020"
},
{
  $push: {
    "dairyDailyLogs.$.breakfast": {
      mealType: 2,
      mealId: "5d758afe89527212109703d1"
    }
  },
  $set: {
    "dairyDailyLogs.$": {
      calories: 200
    }
  }
},
{});
```

the resultant array needs to be this:

```
"dairyDailyLogs":[
   {
      "breakfast":[
         {
            "mealType":1,
            "mealId":"5d758afe89527212109703d1"
         },
         {
            "mealType":1,
            "mealId":"5d758afe89527212109703d2"
         }
      ],
      "calories":200,
      "consumptionDateString":"5/15/2020"
   },
   {
      "breakfast":[
         {
            "mealType":1,
            "mealId":"5d758afe89527212109703d1"
         }
      ],
      "calories":100,
      "consumptionDateString":"5/16/2020"
   }
]
```

Comment: So what's your expected output? I don't understand what you need too. What's the condition to update `calories`?

Comment: Please state your 'condition' or query criteria for which array to update?

Comment: ok so i guess you have checked the array, what i need is:
i want to update calories key and want to push an object in breakfast array where "consumptionDateString":"5/15/2020" should match this or any given date..

sorry! code is not formatted

Comment: this array is part of a mongo document already, what i am looking for is:
to update this subdocument with the required cond.
i am updating my question and providing you the sample result array which i want after operation @igorkf

Comment: @jps thanks for the link...,, appreciate that
ok i will remove my urgency keywords from the question, but i gave it more 2-3hrs and still not able to find any solution to do it in one query..

Comment: @james
please help ! now i made it more clear

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

1) Filter based on the following condition:

```
"dairyDailyLogs.consumptionDateString": "5/15/2020"
```

2) Use `$push` to then append a new meal into the array of the found document.

3) Combine this with `$set` to set the new value of `calories`.

```
db.user_dairy.updateOne({
  "dairyDailyLogs.consumptionDateString": "5/15/2020"
},
{
  $push: {
    "dairyDailyLogs.breakfast": {
      "mealType": 9,
      "mealId": "new ID"
    }
  },
  $set: {
    calories: 200
  }
})
```

Make sure `updateOne` is the correct command for you. This will only update the **first** document it find that matches this criteria.

**Note:** This code is untested.

Comment: hi @james this will update the data in the root of that document (parallel to dailyDairyLogs), as you can see in my edited question, i ve provided the resultant data means i want to updated the data in dairyDailyLogs array

Comment: @AnkurGoel Apologies, it is kind o difficult to tell which specific fields you want adding.. do you want to insert  new breakfast completely? or just add a new meal to the breakfast array? Ill also update my answer to update it in dairyDailyLogs

Comment: thanks 4 update... please look into resultant array (in last of this question),
calories also needs to be update in  dairyDailyLogs arrray..

please just chk resultant array in the ques n compare it with existing array(provided in first portion of this ques)